# Editing date in *.ssf files?

Tags: file-formats, date, trimble, ssf

So my trimble TSC1 Pro XRS (bought in 2000) is getting old I guess and it change byitself the date. I collected data this week, but it indicate from 1998.

I view this info because I can't apply diferential correction. Indeed, the post process file from 1998 aren't avaible anymore.

So I want to change the change the date of the record in *.ssf files.

I tried two different ways : 
- The office pathinder (4.0) SSF record editor. It doesn't allow to edit the date.

- I copy and paste all the record from the *.ssf files in notepad ++, then change the date, then change the files extention in *.ssf. But when I open this files in office pathinder, it doesn't open it correctly.

I'm still looking for any option.

Comment: Any chance you can make one of these files available?

Comment: Sure :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnmdttoqsxetiu5/R102209A.ssf?dl=0

Comment: Are you talking about the file date on the SSF file, or the dates of the points contained in it? The file date shouldn't affect differential correction, and the epochs of the GPS data come from the clocks in the GPS satellites, not the TSC1. If the TSC1 is messing up the epochs in the SSF file, I don't know if I'd trust the spatial locations.

Comment: I'm talking about the point caputred by the GPS, so the dates of the points contained in it.

Viewing my points and the coordinates it's not looking so bad.

Maybe the date problem it's from the inside clock of the TSC1 witch come from 1st from the satellites, then when the TSC1 it's off or disconnected, it's come from a inside batterie (like PC / motherboard system). This batteries it's about 18 years old, i'm expecting it's dead.

That's a 1st point.

However i'm still looking for a solution to edit the date of the point.

Thanks to your help.

Comment: Trimlble is editing my files, but not a clue to the methods or ways.

Comment: Very strange. I think that editing dates and times in SSF files is made difficult on purpose, because the accuracy of the position depends on the accuracy of the time and editing the time is almost always a bad idea. But not if your TSC1 is screwing up the time...

Comment: Well, actually i'm changing my gps tools, and it's was about time!

Anyway, thanks for your support.

Comment: Estoy aplicando tu solución en un archivo .ssf para evadir el "Evento Roll Over" del 6 de abril de 2019, pero me encuentro que al colocar manualmente la semana, tengo un desfase de dos días en la fecha a la que quiero cambiar. Como la extensión "Comprobar Archivo SSF" de Patffinder sólo te permite colocar manualmente el número de la semana,mas no te permite escoger cuál día dentro de esa semana, te ruego si tienes la solución a esto me la compartas por aquí o al correo topocomputer1@gmail.com
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

- Open *.ssf files in office pathinder
- Menu tools> other > check *.ssf files
- Select the right files
- Options : check modify GPS week number manually
- Fill wiht the right GPS week number, that you going to find here : https://www.labsat.co.uk/index.php/en/gps-time-calculator
- Then you can apply the right post-traitement.

Otherwise my date problem seems to come from my TSC1.

Comment: Thanks! All the information was pretty useful for my old Trimble Pro-XT

Answer (score -1):

How to access the Check SSF Files Utility in Pathfinder Office...

[image: How to access the Check SSF Files Utility in Pathfinder Office]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).